# bash multi-threads

Tags: bash, nmap, parallelism

I have a list of IPs and I need to check them for opened ports using `nmap`.
So far, my script is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$1"
port="$2"
echo "STARTING NMAP"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  nmap --host-timeout 15s -n $line -p $2  -oN output.txt | grep "Discovered open port" | awk {'print $6'} | awk -F/ {'print $1'} >> total.txt

done <"$filename"
```

It works great but it's slow and I want to check, for example, 100 IPs from the file at once, instead of running them one by one.

Comment: Are you sure that actually works? What system are you on? On my Arch, the `-oG "$line"` means "print greppable output into the file `$line`" and nmap complains about no target given. Did you mean `-oG -`?

Comment: i know, somebody edited the nmap line and putted -oG ...

Comment: Um, no, that was there from the first version of the question, but never mind. Also, won't that just overwrite `output.txt` with the output of the last IP tested?

Comment: @terdon  yes it does, but if port Opened its putting the ip into total.txt so the output.txt its not going to keep all scans

Comment: This is counterproductive. Nmap's internal parallelism is much more efficient and easier to use: `nmap -iL $filename -p $2 -oG - | awk '/\/open\//{print $2}' >> total.txt` does the same thing but faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$1"
port="$2"
echo "STARTING NMAP"

## Read the file in batches of 100 lines
for((i=100;i<=$(wc -l < "$filename");i+=100)); do 
    head -n "$i" "$filename" | tail -n 100 |
        while IFS= read -r line
        do
          ## Launch the command in the background
          nmap --host-timeout 15s -n $line -p $2  -oN output.txt | 
            grep "Discovered open port" | awk {'print $6'} | 
                awk -F/ {'print $1'} >> total.txt &
        done
    ## Wait for this  batch to finish before moving to the next one
    ## so you don't spam your CPU
    wait
done
```

Comment: Already did, also wanted to vote up but its not allowing me

Comment: @DonaldDuck yes, you need a bit more rep for that. No worries, accepting is more important since it marks the question as answered.

Comment: the code its stopping when large file with ips its putted for check

Comment: @DonaldDuck any error messages?

Comment: no, just stop after first 100

Comment: @DonaldDuck argh, that's because I used `700` as a limit since that's what I had for testing. Try the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -iL  option to pass a file to the list of destination IP addresses, which can be separated by spaces, tabs or new lines and will not need the loop.

Comment: Could you include an example of the exact command the OP would need to run? Also, would that actually run them in parallel or would it still do them one by one?

Comment: using -iL to read the ips from file its the same, nmap will read every line one by one :) so basecly its the same as i did using read line

Comment: Sorry for issues misunderstood the query language. I interpreted that he had to seek the abolition of the loop instead they were simultaneous executions.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Nmap does not need to be multithreaded because it uses socket parallelism to scan many addresses at once. Launching 100 concurrent Nmap processes will almost certainly make your scan slower, because each will interfere with the others' timing checks and congestion avoidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the commands in the background:

```
nmap ... >> total.txt &
```

It may be useful to wait within the script for all background processes to finish:

```
[...]
done <"$filename"
wait
```

Comment: @Huake Laging  please read my question before posting answers/comments

Comment: @DonaldDuck Yeah, you are the kind of user we love here. If Donald Duck is not satisfied with an answer to his first question then the obvious reason is that one of the most experienced users has not even read the question. And, of course, stating such nonsense is much better than pointing out why an answer does not work or does not work as expected.